# CodeIgniter title won't work

Tags: php, codeigniter, controllers

I understand an approach to naming declaring a title for a page in CI can be done like this, which has in the past and if anything within an existing project works.

```
$data['title'] = "myTitle";

$this->load->view("content_home", $data);
```

But for the life of me, now it just will not work!! :(

Anybody any ideas as to why?

Comment: Define "will not work" a little more please. Are you calling title out into some title tags in your view?

Comment: I expect CodeIgniter has a layout file, in which a PHP variable is used to render the title. Find that file and see what's in `<title></title>`.

Comment: Hi @halfer thanks for your response, your reply gave me a light bulb moment :) thank you!! Its fixed now.

Comment: No probs, pleased it now works!

Answer (score 1):

In order to declare a title to a page, you type this in the controller relevant to a page example:

```
public function home(){
        $data["title"] = "my Title";

        $this->load->view("content_home", $data);
    }
```

Within the view in order for this to work this must be inserted:

```
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
```

I had not realised, but this worked for me now after I went back and checked my files properly in my previous project, sorry guys and thanks for the responses.

Comment: If a title can contain user input, or angle brackets, it is safest to escape this with `htmlentities()` in the view.

Answer (score 1):

just fyi you can check if title has been set and if not show something else

```
<title><?php

// check if $title has been set 
if( isset($title) ){ echo $title; } 

// else display generic title 
else { echo "A Website Title" ; } 
 ?></title>
```

that way you will always be covered

Comment: brilliant thanks, I'm fairly new with CI and anything helps right now much appreciated :)